# Why Ubuntu Isn't Recognizing My Laptop Sim Card

Tags: connection, interface, mobile-broadband, linux-headers

I've Installed Linux On A USB Drive. But When I Boot And Run The Ubuntu Linux It Has No Mobile Network Option And It's Saying No WWAW Or Somethin Like This And I Can Not Connect To Internet.

before Installing Linux I had Windows 10 and Sim Card Was Working Correctly And Had Internet.

But In Linux It Isn't Even Recognized.

My Laptop Is HP Pro 612 G2 or Maybe G1
And I Installed Ubuntu 23.10.1 (Mantic Minotaur)

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499363/edit) the question and add more details about your Ubuntu version as well as the laptop model.